# GORM can't work with spring-boot-devtools?

Tags: grails, spring-boot, grails-orm

in spring boot application , build.gradle :

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
compile('org.grails:gorm-hibernate5-spring-boot:6.1.2.RELEASE')
compile('org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:6.1.2.RELEASE')
compile('org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-support:6.1.2.RELEASE')
compile('org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-validation:6.1.2.RELEASE')
```

application would throw exception at runtime.

```
Error performing load command : org.hibernate.HibernateException: Javassist Enhancement failed
```

why?help?

Comment: And removing the devtools all works fine?

Comment: yes, all works fine without devtools .

Answer (score 0):

find Alternatives way.

```
    dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    classpath("org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.7")
}
```

After change code, click Build-》Build project .